# Do not load image if display = none

Tags: javascript, html, image, performance

My website seems to be loading very slowly because all of the images that aren't displayed are loading. How would I go about making it so that the images don't load until they are displayed? Check out the website @ [khom.us](http://khom.us).

HTML:

```
<!-- Project 1-->
    <div data-accordion>
<!-- Number -->
    <a class="number" id="n1">1</a>
<!-- Title -->
    <a class="project slide-link" id="p1" data-slide-id="1" data-control>AA Singles</a>

    <div data-content>
        <div class="info"><a><p>Text.</p></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>


<!-- Project 2-->
    <div data-accordion>
<!-- Number -->
    <a class="number" id="n2">2</a>
<!-- Title -->
    <a class="project slide-link" id="p2" data-slide-id="2" data-control>MM Singles</a> 

    <div data-content>
        <div class="info"><a><p>Text.</p></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

———

```
<!-- Images for Project 1-->
<div class="content">                
<span id="id-01"></span>                
    <div class="slideshow">

    <img class="image image-wide" data-slide-id="1" src="images/AASingle_01.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;" onclick="changeImage()"/>

    <img class="image image-square" src="images/AASingle_02.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

    <img class="image image-square" src="images/AASingle_03.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

    <img class="image image-square" src="images/AASingle_04.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

    </div>
</div>



<!-- Images for Project 2-->
<div class="content">                
<span id="id-02"></span>                
    <div class="slideshow">

    <img class="image image-wide" data-slide-id="2" src="images/MMSingle_01.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;" onclick="changeImage()"/>

    <img class="image image-square" src="images/MMSingle_02.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

    <img class="image image-square" src="images/MMSingle_03.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

    <img class="image image-square" src="images/MMSingle_04.jpg" alt="image" style="display:none;"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.slide-link').click(function() {
 console.log('YES!');
var id = $(this).data('slide-id');
var $img = $('img[data-slide-id='+id+']');
if ($img.hasClass('current-slide')) return;
var $currentSlide = $('.current-slide');
 $currentSlide.fadeOut();
 $currentSlide.removeClass('current-slide');
 $img.addClass('current-slide');
 $img.fadeIn();
});


$('.slideshow img:last-child').addClass('last');
$('.slideshow').each(function(){
    length_img = $(this).children('img').length;
    $(this).next('.counter').children('p').html( '<span class="number">' + $i + '</span>' + ' of ' + length_img);

  });

$('.slideshow').children('img').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut();                                

    $('.slideshow img').removeClass('current-slide');
    length_img = $(this).parent('div').children('img').length;

    if($(this).hasClass('last')){
        $i = 0
        $(this).parent('div').children('img:first').addClass('current-slide').fadeIn();
        $(this).parent('div').next('.counter').children('p').html( '<span class="number">' + ($i+1) + '</span>' + ' of ' + length_img);
    }else{
        $i = $(this).parent('div').next('.counter').children('p').children('span').text();
        $i = parseInt($i);
        console.log($i+1)
        $(this).next('img').fadeIn().addClass('current-slide');
        $(this).parent('div').next('.counter').children('p').html( '<span class="number">' + ($i+1) + '</span>' + ' of ' + length_img);
    }        
});
```

Comment: Compress your images, some of them are ginormous. Run them through a compressor such as https://tinypng.com/ youll save many many mb of data.

Comment: When I visit that site, I get a page that simply says: Khomus (Pronounced "Hummus") and that's it. The network tab shows a bunch of 210 byte images being requested, but I see no images on the page.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I do get to see the website with a couple of images. But the website is as fast as you'd expect from any website. Might be an issue with OP's internet and not the server.

Answer (score 0):

> An image won't begin loading until it knows what its source is. You
>   can include the `<img>` element, so it gets parsed into the DOM but
>   not set the `src` until you decide to show it.

You will notice with this example that you won't get a console entry until you press the button and that's because the image won't load until then.

You can also run this snippet with your developer tools turned on (F12) and select the Network tab. You won't see the request for the image source until you click the button. **Of course, the load can be triggered by whatever you need, it doesn't have to be a button click.**

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btnLoad");
var img = document.getElementById("lazyLoad");

img.addEventListener("load", function(){
  console.log("Image loaded!");
});

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  img.setAttribute("src", "http://www.seanhelvey.com/assets/images/seanhelvey/2014/08/html5-css-javascript-logos.png");
  img.setAttribute("class", "show");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "Logo");
});
```

```css
.hide {display:none;}
.show {display:inline;}
```

```html
<img id="lazyLoad" src="" alt="" class="hide">
<button id="btnLoad">Load Image</button>
```

Comment: This won't work for OP. The code is clearly about a slideshow. Wouldn't be very usefull if visitors have to click a button to see each slide. I was thinking about a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect a change in the css attribute and set the src attribute on the trigger :)

Comment: @icecub The button click is just an example. What actually triggers the load can be anything.